# Differentiating with fractions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Would somebody be able to tell me how to differentiate

$2x^2(\frac {300-4x}{6x})$

?

Mainly, how would I be able to get the fraction into the normal $ax^2+bx+c$ form to differentiate?

Thank you!

Comment: Remember that $A(\frac BC)=\frac{A\times(B)}C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice that

$$2x^2\left(\frac{300-4x}{6x}\right) = \frac{1}{3}x(300-4x) = -\frac{4}{3}x^2+100x$$

by letting one of the $x$'s in $2x^2$ cancel out with the $x$ in the denominator.